# Best practices + syntax for implementing a "contextmanager" in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, raii, contextmanager

Our Python codebase has metrics-related code that looks like this:

```
class Timer:
    def __enter__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.start = time.time()

    def __exit__(self):
        elapsed = time.time() - self.start
        log.info('%s took %f seconds' % (self.name, elapsed))

...

with Timer('foo'):
    do some work

with Timer('bar') as named_timer:
    do some work
    named_timer.some_mutative_method()
    do some more work
```

In Python's terminology, the timer is a *contextmanager*.

Now we want to implement the same thing in C++, with an equally nice syntax. Unfortunately, C++ doesn't have `with`. So the "obvious" idiom would be (classical RAII)

```
class Timer {
    Timer(std::string name) : name_(std::move(name)) {}
    ~Timer() { /* ... */ }
};

if (true) {
    Timer t("foo");
    do some work
}
if (true) {
    Timer named_timer("bar");
    do some work
    named_timer.some_mutative_method();
    do some more work
}
```

But this is extremely ugly syntactic salt: it's many lines longer than it needs to be, we had to introduce a name `t` for our "unnamed" timer (and the code breaks silently if we forget that name)... it's just ugly.

**What are some syntactic idioms that people have used to deal with "contextmanagers" in C++?**

---

I've thought of this abusive idea, which reduces the line-count but doesn't get rid of the name `t`:

```
// give Timer an implicit always-true conversion to bool
if (auto t = Timer("foo")) {
    do some work
}
```

Or this architectural monstrosity, which I don't even trust *myself* to use correctly:

```
Timer("foo", [&](auto&) {
    do some work
});
Timer("bar", [&](auto& named_timer) {
    do some work
    named_timer.some_mutative_method();
    do some more work
});
```

where the constructor of `Timer` actually invokes the given lambda (with argument `*this`) and does the logging all in one go.

Neither of those ideas seems like a "best practice", though. Help me out here!

---

Another way to phrase the question might be: If you were designing `std::lock_guard` from scratch, how would you do it so as to eliminate as much boilerplate as possible?  `lock_guard` is a perfect example of a contextmanager: it's a utility, it's intrinsically RAII, and you hardly ever want to bother naming it.

Comment: You may create block without introduce `if (true)`

Comment: The generic solution is just raii. Is your specific question how to write a timer to print elapsed time at the end?

Comment: I actually think your lambda solution is kinda nice.

Comment: Could you get your constructor to accept a generic lambda like that? It might be easier to just write `[&](Timer &) { ... }`, let the constructor capture it in a `std::function<void(Timer&)>` and call it with `*this`.

Comment: While C++ does allow you to introduce a scope with `{ }` as opposed to `if (true) { }`, I consider that a stylistic faux pas on par with `for (;;) { }` (where the stylish syntax is `while (true) { }`). Anyway, omitting the `if (true)` doesn't change the number of lines of code involved, or the necessity of naming the timer, or any of the actual problems with that code, so the style point is irrelevant — we can agree to disagree about it.

Comment: @Barry The question is what's the best practice for the API of such a "contextmanager" class — the sort of thing for which you'd use `with` in Python. This question probably only makes sense if you're bilingual in Python and C++.

Comment: "I consider that a stylistic faux pas" You have very strange sense of style (or is it sense of humour?)

Comment: @Quuxplusone Yes and that's a super broad question whose answer is just RAII. `ifstream`, `lock_guard`, even `unique_ptr` are all context manager (which is two words, btw) implementations. If you just want to ask about timing code, I suggest you narrow the scope of the question to that.

Comment: @Barry `contextmanager` is one word; `ifstream` and `unique_ptr` are not contextmanagers, despite using RAII. Again, if you don't speak Python, the question might not make sense without a certain amount of background research on your part. Part of the motivation for the question is that C++ doesn't have a formal notion of "contextmanager" as distinct from "class-that-holds-some-resources". In Python, the distinction is roughly `__enter__/__exit__` versus `__init__/__del__`.

Comment: @Quuxplusone [Context manager](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) is two words. There is, separately, a decorated *named* [`contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager). Be less focused on demonstrating your superiority over everybody, and more focused on writing a good question.

Answer (score 13):

It's possible to mimic the Python syntax and semantics quite closely. The following test case compiles and has largely similar semantics to what you'd have in Python:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/pythonic-with-33088614
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdio>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
[...]
int main() {
   // with Resource("foo"):
   //   print("* Doing work!\n")
   with<Resource>("foo") >= [&] {
      std::cout << "1. Doing work\n";
   };

   // with Resource("foo", True) as r:
   //   r.say("* Doing work too")
   with<Resource>("bar", true) >= [&](auto &r) {
      r.say("2. Doing work too");
   };

   for (bool succeed : {true, false}) {
      // Shorthand for:
      // try:
      //   with Resource("bar", succeed) as r:
      //     r.say("Hello")
      //     print("* Doing work\n")
      // except:
      //   print("* Can't do work\n")

      with<Resource>("bar", succeed) >= [&](auto &r) {
         r.say("Hello");
         std::cout << "3. Doing work\n";
      } >= else_ >= [&] {
         std::cout << "4. Can't do work\n";
      };
   }
}
```

That's given

```
class Resource {
   const std::string str;

  public:
   const bool successful;
   Resource(const Resource &) = delete;
   Resource(Resource &&) = delete;
   Resource(const std::string &str, bool succeed = true)
       : str(str), successful(succeed) {}
   void say(const std::string &s) {
      std::cout << "Resource(" << str << ") says: " << s << "\n";
   }
};
```

The `with` free function passes all the work to the `with_impl` class:

```
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
with_impl<T> with(Ts &&... args) {
   return with_impl<T>(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
}
```

How do we get there? First, we need a `context_manager` class: the traits class that implements the `enter` and `exit` methods - the equivalents of Python's `__enter__` and `__exit__`. As soon as the `is_detected` type trait gets rolled into C++, this class can also easily forward to the compatible `enter` and `exit` methods of the class type `T`, thus mimicking Python's semantics even better. As it stands, the context manager is rather simple:

```
template <typename T>
class context_manager_base {
  protected:
   std::optional<T> context;

  public:
   T &get() { return context.value(); }

   template <typename... Ts>
   std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<T, Ts...>, bool> enter(Ts &&... args) {
      context.emplace(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
      return true;
   }
   bool exit(std::exception_ptr) {
      context.reset();
      return true;
   }
};

template <typename T>
class context_manager : public context_manager_base<T> {};
```

Let's see how this class would be specialized to wrap the `Resource` objects, or `std::FILE *`.

```
template <>
class context_manager<Resource> : public context_manager_base<Resource> {
  public:
   template <typename... Ts>
   bool enter(Ts &&... args) {
      context.emplace(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
      return context.value().successful;
   }
};

template <>
class context_manager<std::FILE *> {
   std::FILE *file;

  public:
   std::FILE *get() { return file; }
   bool enter(const char *filename, const char *mode) {
      file = std::fopen(filename, mode);
      return file;
   }
   bool leave(std::exception_ptr) { return !file || (fclose(file) == 0); }
   ~context_manager() { leave({}); }
};
```

The implementation of the core functionality is in the `with_impl` type. Note how the exception handling within the suite (the first lambda) and the `exit` function mimic Python behavior.

```
static class else_t *else_;
class pass_exceptions_t {};

template <typename T>
class with_impl {
   context_manager<T> mgr;
   bool ok;
   enum class Stage { WITH, ELSE, DONE } stage = Stage::WITH;
   std::exception_ptr exception = {};

  public:
   with_impl(const with_impl &) = delete;
   with_impl(with_impl &&) = delete;
   template <typename... Ts>
   explicit with_impl(Ts &&... args) {
      try {
         ok = mgr.enter(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
      } catch (...) {
         ok = false;
      }
   }
   template <typename... Ts>
   explicit with_impl(pass_exceptions_t, Ts &&... args) {
      ok = mgr.enter(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
   }
   ~with_impl() {
      if (!mgr.exit(exception) && exception) std::rethrow_exception(exception);
   }
   with_impl &operator>=(else_t *) {
      assert(stage == Stage::ELSE);
      return *this;
   }
   template <typename Fn>
   std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_r_v<void, Fn, decltype(mgr.get())>, with_impl &>
   operator>=(Fn &&fn) {
      assert(stage == Stage::WITH);
      if (ok) try {
            std::forward<Fn>(fn)(mgr.get());
         } catch (...) {
            exception = std::current_exception();
         }
      stage = Stage::ELSE;
      return *this;
   }
   template <typename Fn>
   std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_r_v<bool, Fn, decltype(mgr.get())>, with_impl &>
   operator>=(Fn &&fn) {
      assert(stage == Stage::WITH);
      if (ok) try {
            ok = std::forward<Fn>(fn)(mgr.get());
         } catch (...) {
            exception = std::current_exception();
         }
      stage = Stage::ELSE;
      return *this;
   }
   template <typename Fn>
   std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_r_v<void, Fn>, with_impl &> operator>=(Fn &&fn) {
      assert(stage != Stage::DONE);
      if (stage == Stage::WITH) {
         if (ok) try {
               std::forward<Fn>(fn)();
            } catch (...) {
               exception = std::current_exception();
            }
         stage = Stage::ELSE;
      } else {
         assert(stage == Stage::ELSE);
         if (!ok) std::forward<Fn>(fn)();
         if (!mgr.exit(exception) && exception) std::rethrow_exception(exception);
         stage = Stage::DONE;
      }
      return *this;
   }
   template <typename Fn>
   std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_r_v<bool, Fn>, with_impl &> operator>=(Fn &&fn) {
      assert(stage != Stage::DONE);
      if (stage == Stage::WITH) {
         if (ok) try {
               ok = std::forward<Fn>(fn)();
            } catch (...) {
               exception = std::current_exception();
            }
         stage = Stage::ELSE;
      } else {
         assert(stage == Stage::ELSE);
         if (!ok) std::forward<Fn>(fn)();
         if (!mgr.exit(exception) && exception) std::rethrow_exception(exception);
         stage = Stage::DONE;
      }
      return *this;
   }
};
```

Comment: That's super ugly and the solution is worse than the problem itself, and the problem is contrived as it is.

Comment: The "solution" is library code. You write it once and never look at it again. As for the syntax: it's pretty much minimal. `with<Resource>("foo") >= [&] { ... }` is all it takes (vs. Python equivalent `with Resource("foo"): ...`. I urge you to come up with less ugly solution within the realm of C++ :) The problem is not contrived at all, since it's worth self-documenting that a code block is using a resource.

Comment: I never thought it made sense to force the idioms of one language (python) into a different language (c++). That's why I think it's contrived. If you can the standards committed to tackle this, and give you compiler support, then go for it. But in production code I'd never resort to these tricks.

Comment: I don’t quite know where standards come into play. C++ has RAII, but it’s often hard to tell which objects manage what one might consider “resources”. This just documents that fact, and an an added bonus lets one not write RAII wrappers for every dog gone raw C API resource handle, should one not wish to do so. That is optional of course. Sometimes it’s useful. In any case, this is some syntax sugar that injects RAII as a type extension where desired, and otherwise just documents the RAII types used as being resources. Usually these types have higher use cost than `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: Looking back: if you think the library code on the answer above is “ugly”, take a look at how the `unique_ptr` looks in any C++ library implementation of your choice. It makes this code look wonderful :)

Answer (score 11):

Edit: After reading Dai's comment more carefully, and thinking a bit more, I realized this is a poor choice for C++ RAII. Why? Because you are logging in the destructor, this means you are doing io, and io can throw. C++ destructors should not emit exceptions. With python, writing a throwing `__exit__` isn't necessarily awesome either, it can cause you to drop your first exception on the floor. But in python, you definitively know whether the code in the context manager has caused an exception or not. If it caused an exception, you can just omit your logging in `__exit__` and pass through the exception. I leave my original answer below in case you have a context manager which doesn't risk throwing on exit.

The C++ version is 2 lines longer than the python version, one for each curly brace. If C++ is only two lines longer than python, that's doing well. Context managers are designed for this specific thing, RAII is more general and provides a strict superset of the functionality. If you want to know best practice, you already found it: have an anonymous scope and create the object at the beginning. This is idiomatic. You may find it ugly coming from python, but in the C++ world it's just fine. The same way someone from C++ will find context managers ugly in certain situations. FWIW I use both languages professionally and this doesn't bother me at all.

That said, I'll provide a cleaner approach for anonymous context managers. Your approach with constructing Timer with a lambda and immediately letting it destruct is pretty weird, so you're right to be suspicious. A better approach:

```
template <class F>
void with_timer(const std::string & name, F && f) {
    Timer timer(name);
    f();
}
```

Usage:

```
with_timer("hello", [&] {
    do something;
});
```

This is equivalent to the anonymous context manager, in the sense that none of Timer's methods can be called other than construction and destruction. Also, it uses the "normal" class, so you can use the class when you need a named context manager, and this function otherwise. You could obviously write with_lock_guard in a very similar way. There it's even better as lock_guard doesn't have any member functions you're missing out on.

All that said, would I use with_lock_guard, or approve code written by a teammate that added in such a utility? No. One or two extra lines of code just doesn't matter; this function doesn't add enough utility to justify it's own existence. YMMV.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need `if( true )`, C++ has "anonymous scopes" which can be used to restrict a scope's lifetime in much the same was as Python's `with` or C#s `using` (well, C# also has anonymous scopes too).

Like so:

```
doSomething();
{
    Time timer("foo");
    doSomethingElse();
}
doMoreStuff();
```

Just use bare curly-brackets.

However, I disagree with your idea of using RAII-semantics to instrument code like this as the `timer` destructor is non-trivial and has side-effects by-design. It might be ugly and repetitive, but I feel explicitly calling named `startTimer`, `stopTimer` and `printTimer` methods make the program more "correct" and self-documenting. Side-effects are bad, m'key?

Comment: I don't understand why you don't think RAII is appropriate here. All RAII destructors are going to be non-trivial since they have to release some resource. If it was trivial, the RAII class would be redundant.

Comment: @pcarter Actually, I think Dai makes a good point. In this case, the destructor is doing logging, which means io, which means it could actually throw. Throwing destructors are bad.

Comment: A try-catch will stop an exception from escaping the destructor. And it turns out that boost provides a RAII based timer (that logs) see: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/timer/doc/cpu_timers.html. Maybe the OP could just use boost's class.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently started a C++ project to mimic Python's context manager as I migrate a python code base over to C++, found at https://github.com/batconjurer/contextual.

For this flow, you need to define a resource manager derived from an interface named `IResource`. Below, this is called `Timer`. It is in this class that the `enter` and `exit` functions are implemented. The context is just the code block that requires the resources, so it is passed via anonymous function.

The resource manager expects you to implement the IData struct which is uses to store the acquired resources. It actually only keeps a pointer to an IData instance.

For your use case, the following is an example implementation that compiles with C++17.

```cpp
#include "include/contextual.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using namespace Contextual;

namespace Contextual {

    struct IData {
        std::string name;
        std::time_t start_time = std::time(NULL);
        void reset_time() {

            std::cout << "Time before restart: " << start_time << "\n";
            std::time(&start_time);
            std::cout << "Time after restart: " << start_time << "\n";
        };
    };

    class Timer : public IResource<IData> {
    private:
        IData _data;

        void enter() override {
            std::time(&resources->start_time);
        }

        void exit(std::optional<std::exception> e) override {
            double elapsed_time = std::time(NULL) - resources->start_time;
            std::cout << resources->name << " took " << elapsed_time << " seconds.\n";
            if (e) {
                throw e.value();
            }
        }

    public:

        Timer(std::string &&name) : IResource<IData>(_data), _data(IData{name}){};

    };

};

int main(){

    With {
        Timer(std::string("Foo")) + Context{
            [&](IData* time_data) {

                std::chrono::milliseconds sleeptime(5000);
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(sleeptime);     // In place of "Do some work"
                time_data->reset_time();     // In place of "some_mutative_function()"
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(sleeptime);    // In place of "Do some work"
            }
        }
    };


}
```

There are some nuisances I'm still working on (for example the fact that the IData struct had to be stored as a instance variable of the Timer since only a pointer to it is kept by IResource). And of course C++ exceptions aren't the nicest things.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Dai's answer, I ended up with this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

class Timer
{
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point startTime;
    public:
    Timer(): startTime(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()){};

    void elapsed()
    {
        auto endTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
        std::cout << elapsedTime.count() << std::endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    {
        Timer timer=Timer();
        std::cout << "This is some work" << std::endl;
        timer.elapsed();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm much more fluent in python than in c++; I'm not sure if it's idiomatic but it works for me.